# What is the 7th line?

Tags: sequence

```
.2
<,1,<
^0^.0^0.^
>1>1>1>,1>1>1>1,>
v2v2v2v2v2v2v2v.2v2v2v2v2v2v2v2.v
<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<,1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1<1,<
```

What comes next in this sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think:

> `^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^.0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0.^`

Since:

> The arrow turns clockwise, the numbers go `2101 2101 2101 ...` (I think) and the dots/commas are at positions of $2^{\text{line number}-1}$ and twice that and alternate between lines. Then we have two iterations + 1 more character.

Comment: Guvf vf tbbq. Gur ahzoref tb 0,1,0,1,2,1, gura onpx gb 0. "<" naq "i" zrna tb onpx be tb qbja n ahzore, gura "^" naq ">" zrna tb sbejneq be hc n ahzore, fb 0f vafgrnq bs 2f. [rot13](http://rot13.com)

Comment: @uwnojpjm Ohg va yvar 1, gur neebjf jbhyq cbvag qbja. Fubhyqa'g yvar 2 unir -1 vafgrnq bs 1?

Comment: @benzene, ohg gur svefg yvar unf gb unir bar punenpgre. Vg zvtug or orggre gb fgneg ng 1?

Comment: @benzene, edit it how you think, and I'll accept your edit.

Comment: @uwnojpjm is this good?

Comment: Yeah, you got it. :-)